# Finding all the possible dimensions of Kernel with a nilpotent linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, nilpotence, canonical-transformation

Let $V$ be a 5-dimensional vector space, and $T : V → V$ a nilpotent linear transformation of order $k$, where $1 ≤ k ≤ 5$. Make a list of all the possible dimensions of $\ker(T), \ker(T^2), \ldots , \ker(T^{k−1})$ and the corresponding canonical forms of $T$.

I'm not sure where to start so I started with a few difference branches of thought. Would the eigenvalues here have to be zero because to be nilpotent $T^k=0$? Would the dimensions be as simple as $\ker(T)$ having dimension $1$, $\ker(T^2)$ having dimension $2$, etc?

Comment: Presumably you know about the Jordan canonical form, based on your question. It is a good idea to start by writing down the possible canonical forms of a nilpotent matrix of order $k$, then compute the kernel for each of these.

Comment: And yes, the eigenvalues are going to be zero. But the answer to the second question is negative in general - I think you are secretly working with a maximal rank nilpotent matrix.

Comment: ker(T) can have any dimension from 1 up to 5. Consider the zero matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of the kernel of $T$  is the number of Jordan blocks in the reduced form of the matrix.

$\dim\ker A^2-\dim\ker A$ is the number of Jordan blocks of size $\ge 2$, &c.

**Added:**

*Jordan's reduction theorem* asserts any matrix over an algebraically closed field (say $\mathbf C$) is similar to a block diagonal matrix, where each (Jordan) block is an upper triangular matrix,  associated to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ and has the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda&1&0&\dots&0\\0 &\lambda&1&\dots&0\\[-2ex]\vdots&&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\dots&1\\0&0&0&\dots&\lambda
\end{bmatrix}$$
For a nilpotent matrix, the only eigenvalue is $0$, and the matrix, in a Jordan basis, has the form
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&\dots&0\\0 &0&1&\dots&0\\[-2ex]\vdots&&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\dots&1\\0&0&0&\dots&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Note that, $$J^2=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0&\dots&0\\[-2ex]0 &0&0&1&\ddots&0\\[-2ex]\vdots&&&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\dots&1\\0&0&0&0&\dots&0\\0&0&0&0&\dots&0
\end{bmatrix},\quad\&\text c.$$
Hence, if $J$ has dimension $k$, $J^{k-1}\ne 0,\enspace J^k=0$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining Jordan blocks please?

Comment: @user319635: I've added some details. Is that clearer?

Comment: Thank you! Okay, so then in my case the dimension of $\ker(T) =1$, the dimension of $\ker(T^2)$, etc, $dim(\ker(T^5))=4$? Is this what they mean by make a list?

Comment: $\dim\ker T=1$ says you have only one Jordan block (necessarily of dimension 5), so $T^5=0$ (and $\dim\ker T^4=5$). If $\dim\ker T$ were equal to $2$, you would have two Jordan blocks, one of dimension $4$ and one of dimension $1$, **or** one of dimension $3$ and one of dimension $2$. To determine the case, we use the sequence of dimensions.