# Is $1\le 3\le 4\le 4$ a possibility for the sequence $k_1\le k_2\le k_3\le k_4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let  $T$ be a $4\times 4$ real matrix such that $T^4=0$ .Let $k_i=\dim  \ker T^i;1\le i\le 4$.

Is
$1\le 3\le 4\le 4$

a possibility for the sequence $k_1\le k_2\le k_3\le k_4$?

**My try**:

Consider the map $T$ given by $T(e_1)=0;T(e_2)=T(e_3)=e_1;T(e_4)=e_2$ where $\{e_i:1\le i\le 4\}$ is  the standard basis of $\Bbb R^4$.Here $k_1=1$

Then  $T^2(e_2)=T^2(e_3)=0;T^2(e_4)=e_1$.Here $k_2=3$

Also $T^3(e_i)=T^4(e_i)=0\forall i$ .Here $k_3=k_4=4$

Hence such a possibility is there.

But unfortunately the answer is given as **NO**.

Where am I going wrong in the given one?Please help.

Comment: dim ker T=2 not 1. As well as $T(e_1)=0$ you have $T(e_2-e_3)=0$.

Comment: This will help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709475/finding-all-the-possible-dimensions-of-kernel-with-a-nilpotent-linear-transforma

Comment: I got your point ;But can it be proven that such a possibility never exists @almagest

Comment: @learnmore Have you looked at the question KushaiBhuyan suggested? Are you familiar with the Jordan form?

Comment: Another one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711949/how-to-list-all-possible-dimension-of-kert-kert2-kertk-1-and?rq=1. Jordan forms is the easiest way to understand this problem. Are u familiar with this form?

Comment: No not so much ;can't it be done in some other way@almagest